# Grabbing the mouse cursor in GLFW

Tags: c++, sdl, glfw

My question is if GLFW has an easy way of 'grabbing' the mouse cursor.  SDL has a grab cursor function that clamps the mouse inside the window area.  Does GLFW have an equivalent for SDL_WM_GrabInput?

Comment: As far as I know, it *used* to in version 2. I think if you set the mouse cursor to hidden when it was in the window, it clamped it. Unfortunately, I'm also searching for how to do this in version 3.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the system cursor to be visible and restricted to the window then no, that is not currently possible.  However, if you want the system cursor to be grabbed and hidden, for example if you wish to draw your own cursor or implement an free-look camera, then you can use disabled cursor mode.  In that case, see [glfwSetInputMode](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html) and `GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED`.

Mouse input will then act as if the cursor is completely unrestricted, but it will in fact be unable to leave the window until you change the mode back or the window loses focus.

Comment: If I set the cursor to `GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED` do I have to manually keep track of the mouse position if I want to keep the x,y coords clamped to the window dimensions?

Comment: Yes, you will need to keep track of that manually in that case.